# Cannot assign to property: 'detailDic' is a 'let' constant

Tags: swift, uikit, segue

I have issue with my code, it tells me "Cannot assign to property: 'detailDic' is a 'let' constant"
and my build failed

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "detail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let dic = cities[indexPath.row]
                let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
                detailVC.detailDic = dic
                
                
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried this and got this error "Result of operator '==' is unused" and it runs but it will be crash

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "detail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let dic = cities[indexPath.row]
                let detailVC = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
                detailVC.detailDic == dic
                
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my problem

i used `let detailDic = [String:String]()`

that most be `var detailDic = [String:String]()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).